# Pack website as executable for Windows using PHP's builtin server

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking to build a standalone, local version of my webservice.

The website runs using Javascript, PHP and PostgreSQL.

I can use a local browser, which connects to the localhost, so I do not need to worry about that.

The website does not need a database for it self, as it connects to an external PostgreSQL database.

So far, I have successfully used PHP's own built-in webserver: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

However, how do now I include the PostgreSQL extension?

Comment: Your website does not rely on PHP? If so, why did you include that tag?

Comment: Wow, I got downvoted fast. I included PHP as a tag I am using PHP. If one finished reading the text, he or she would find this out as well.

Comment: Your original post said nothing about relying on PHP, just Apache and JavaScript. Then your question is off-topic for SO in as much as it asks for software,  " Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: "It would save me the effort to port the PHP and Javascript code." - Originally it said this. I eventually changed Apache to PHP ("that relies only on PHP").

Comment: Your edits do make it clearer, many people found your original question confusing about the PHP part, I'm just trying to help you understand.

Comment: Okay, I might have been to vague, as I made an error confusing Apache with PHP in a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PHP 5.4, there is a built-in server for PHP.

So all you need to do is bundle your PHP installation with your "website", and provide a convenient .BAT file that does something like:

```
@echo off
start /min bin/PHP/php.exe -S localhost:8000
timeout /t 1
start http://localhost:8000/index.php
```

This will start the PHP server, pause for a second, then get the default browser with the index file.

Comment: who give it a -1 lol....

Comment: Thanks, Niet the Dark Absol. I will probably write a small program for it then that incorporates a browser and starts and stops the PHP service.

Comment: PostgreSQL is still a pain to get working though, and may make this not the right answer.